# Count distinct loop in sql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to pull unique active users before a date.

So specifically, I have a date range (let's say August - November) where I want to know the cumulative unique active users on or before a day within a month.

So, the pseudocode would look something like this:

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT USERS) FROM USER_DB

WHERE
Month = [loop through months 8-11]
AND
DAY <= [day in loop of 1:31]

---

The output I desire is something Like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[step-by-step demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=aeac08a9a694d4e1655bd8b4595320e3)

```
SELECT 
    mydate,
    SUM(                           -- 3
        COUNT(DISTINCT username)   -- 1, 2
    ) OVER (ORDER BY mydate)       -- 3
FROM t
GROUP BY mydate                    -- 2
```

1. `GROUP BY` your date and count the users
2. Because you don't want to count ALL user accesses, but only one access per user and day, you need to add the `DISTINCT`
3. This is a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html). This one aggregates all counts which where previously done cumulatively.

---

If you want to get unique user over ALL days (count a user only on its first access) you can filter the users with a `DISTINCT ON` clause first:

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6f639734f1bf974f99318e4da9b9f439)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (username)
    *
FROM t
ORDER BY username, mydate
```

This yields:

```
SELECT 
   mydate,
   SUM(
       COUNT(*)
   ) OVER (ORDER BY mydate)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (username)
        *
    FROM t
    ORDER BY username, mydate
) s
GROUP BY mydate
```